# App layout problems with Right-To-Left languages

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I have developed an app in English language. When i change my android language to a right-to-left (later rtl) language , my app goes rtl layout but I don't want that. I want my app layout to stay left-to-right (later ltr) whether android language is ltr or rtl.
I know there is layoutdirection in a activity attributes but it's not for APIs below 17.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this in manifest

```
    android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd still say to use this:

```
Add in styles.xml in your Base App theme style:

<item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
```

17+ is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

with support rtl your layout in english is still ltr.

rtl is on only for languages how japanese and so on.

the [most devices](https://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions) are already API 17+.

On emulator or device you can change main language, so you can use rtl or rtl layout depend on selected language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all of your resources **(layouts, strings, drawable ... etc)** in rtl language folder like
**layout-ar** and remove default layout folder
also use **values-ar, drawable-ar .... etc** only

i think this will force android to read from it.